# How to extract text from multiple paragraph in div poltergeist/capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, capybara, poltergeist

I am using this command to extract p tag

```
session.all('.entry p')
```

Giving results

```
[#<Capybara::Element tag="p" path="//HTML[1]/BODY[1]/DIV[3]/DIV[1]/SECTION[1]/DIV[1]/ARTICLE[1]/DIV[3]/P[1]">, 
#<Capybara::Element tag="p" path="//HTML[1]/BODY[1]/DIV[3]/DIV[1]/SECTION[1]/DIV[1]/ARTICLE[1]/DIV[3]/P[2]">, 
#<Capybara::Element tag="p" path="//HTML[1]/BODY[1]/DIV[3]/DIV[1]/SECTION[1]/DIV[1]/ARTICLE[1]/DIV[3]/P[3]">, 
#<Capybara::Element tag="p" path="//HTML[1]/BODY[1]/DIV[3]/DIV[1]/SECTION[1]/DIV[1]/ARTICLE[1]/DIV[3]/P[4]">,
#<Capybara::Element tag="p" path="//HTML[1]/BODY[1]/DIV[3]/DIV[1]/SECTION[1]/DIV[1]/ARTICLE[1]/DIV[3]/P[5]">, 
#<Capybara::Element tag="p" path="//HTML[1]/BODY[1]/DIV[3]/DIV[1]/SECTION[1]/DIV[1]/ARTICLE[1]/DIV[3]/P[6]">,
#<Capybara::Element tag="p" path="//HTML[1]/BODY[1]/DIV[3]/DIV[1]/SECTION[1]/DIV[1]/ARTICLE[1]/DIV[3]/P[7]">, 
#<Capybara::Element tag="p" path="//HTML[1]/BODY[1]/DIV[3]/DIV[1]/SECTION[1]/DIV[1]/ARTICLE[1]/DIV[3]/P[8]">, 
#<Capybara::Element tag="p" path="//HTML[1]/BODY[1]/DIV[3]/DIV[1]/SECTION[1]/DIV[1]/ARTICLE[1]/DIV[3]/P[9]">, 
#<Capybara::Element tag="p" path="//HTML[1]/BODY[1]/DIV[3]/DIV[1]/SECTION[1]/DIV[1]/ARTICLE[1]/DIV[3]/P[10]">]
```

Now i want to extract all text from p node, i know there is loop method to merge all paragraph text, is there any other way. capybara provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `#all` is a [Capybara::Result](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Result). The doc says:

> A Result represents a collection of Node::Element on the page. It is
>   possible to interact with this collection similar to an Array because
>   it implements Enumerable [...]

Thus, you may interact with it as with a enumerable, it does not offer any method you're asking for.

You can do this to retrieve the concatenated content:

```
session.all('.entry p').map(&:text).join
```

According to your tag "web-scraping" I assume you're using capybara for web scraping, and not for testing. As capybara's main purpose is for testing it does not have a built-in method for what you're asking for.

If you're implementing a test though you should rather do something like this (I used RSpec here):

```
within('.entry') do
  expect(page).to have_text 'something'
end
```

Or, if you really need to be very specific about the location of the spec (which in most cases is unnecessary) you should test each element on it's own:

```
expect(session.all('.entry p')[0]).to have_content 'something'
expect(session.all('.entry p')[1]).to have_content 'something else'
```

And just as a last sidenote: For web scraping there are better options than capybara.

Comment: I am doing web scraping, crawling. Thanks

Comment: so did i answer your question? if so, please accept this as the answer. if not, please elaborate on your specific use case.

Comment: I am thinking of using regular expression to extract the text from all the  paragraph. any idea on this? for time being your answer is quite usable no doubt.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I gave you a solution to extract all the text from all paragraphs. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Did not you use regular expression???. This can be used to extract all text inside paragraphs without loop through it.

Comment: No, I did not use a regular expression. Where do you see one?

Comment: Will let you know after using it. By the way thanks for your efforts.